# Automatic button Click in Android

Tags: android-studio

I am working on a project and I have the following doubt. I have a function where I have defined a button. Now I cannot replace the button by a function because there are lot of issues in the code. So I want to press the button automatically after a specific time interval. I wish to activate the button press activity after every 15 minutes. I have created one more class i.e. the BroadcastReceiver class, I get a toast after every 15 minutes from the Broadcast receiver class. But now I want to initiate the button press activity rather than the toast from the BroacastReceive class. The button is in main activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can not really press the button automatically .

The best solution i can suggest is make a function. then place the code which is inside [onclicklistener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) into that function. so call that function from inside the [onclicklistener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and from the bradcastreciver too . now single function is reused and you get what you want.

Comment: I am using the alarm function to call the BroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: Is there any way where I can call the onclicklistner() from another class

Comment: no buddy this is not possible. the best solution i can suggest is make a function. then place the code which is inside onclicklistener() into that function.  so call that function from inside the onclicklistener() and from the bradcastreciver too . now single function is reused and you get what you want.

Comment: no the answer is you cant really call onclicklistener from anywhere .

Comment: glad to help you . you can accept the answer as correct answer if this is what you wanted .